# Store variable values into an array and pass the array through a for loop?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to accomplish the following.

Get the values of the u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9 and store it in an array somehow.

Pass the array through the for loop.

What I am trying to achieve is this. My website allows users to make up to 4 picks. Some users will have 1 pick others might have 2, 3 or 4 picks.

For ex.

user1
pick 1
pick 2

user2
pick 1
pick 2
pick 3

user4
pick 1

...

user9

I want the code to append remaining placeholder picks to all users. So user1 has made 2 picks. I would like to append placeholder pick 3 and pick 4 to user1.

Using the example above it the output would look like the following.

user1
pick 1
pick 2
***pick 3
pick 4***

user2
pick 1
pick 2
pick 3
***pick 4***

user4
pick 1
***pick 2
pick 3
pick 4***

...

user9
***pick 1
pick 2
pick 3
pick 4***

I attempted this with the following code but couldn't get the values to store in the array and the array to work in the for loop.

```
var u2 = $('.single-user-picks#user2 .user-single-pick').length;
var u3 = $('.single-user-picks#user3 .user-single-pick').length;
var u4 = $('.single-user-picks#user4 .user-single-pick').length;
var u5 = $('.single-user-picks#user5 .user-single-pick').length;
var u6 = $('.single-user-picks#user6 .user-single-pick').length;
var u7 = $('.single-user-picks#user7 .user-single-pick').length;
var u8 = $('.single-user-picks#user8 .user-single-pick').length;
var u9 = $('.single-user-picks#user9 .user-single-pick').length;

var uA = [ u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9 ];
var uID = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ];

for ( var i = 0; i < uA.length; i++ ) {
    if (uA[] == 3) {
        $('.single-user-picks#user' + uID[] + '').append('<span>Pick 4</span>');
    }
    if (uA[] == 2) {
        $('.single-user-picks#user' + uID[] + '').append('<span>Pick 4</span><span>Pick 3</span>');
    }
    if (uA[] == 1) {
        $('.single-user-picks#user' + uID[] + '').append('<span>Pick 4</span><span>Pick 3</span><span>Pick 2</span>');
    }
    if (uA[] == 0) {
        $('.single-user-picks#user' + uID[] + '').append('<span>Pick 4</span><span>Pick 3</span><span>Pick 2</span><span>Pick 1</span>');
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a number inside your []'s. Probably i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the index of the array inside the for loop.
So, `uA[i]` instead of `uA[]` and `uID[i]` instead of `uID[]`